# Firefox sees element where PhantomJS does not when using Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have been looking around for quite a long time now to find a solution to my problem, hope someone here can think of something that could help.

I have a working selenium script (in Python) working with the Firefox driver to connect on a website. When using PhantomJS as driver, it doesn't work anymore.

The form is generated by javascript and is on a https website. Here is the code of the user input :

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
document.writeln("<input class=\"textform\" type=\"text\" id=\"user\" name=\"user\" size=\"" + size + "\" tabindex=1 onFocus=\"hadFocus(true)\">");
</script>
```

Here is the part of the script looking for it : (working on firefox but not PhantomJS)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get([MY URL])

print driver.page_source

driver.find_element_by_id("user").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("user").send_keys([MY USER ID])
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys([MY PASS])
driver.find_element_by_name("login_btn").click()

html_source = driver.page_source

print html_source

driver.close()
```

And here is the error I get :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
```

If I print the `page_source` just after reaching the page, Firefox shows the right source code, where PhantomJS only has : `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Do you think of anything that could be the cause of this ?

Comment: Can you show us the code sample, not just the element? Is it Python or Java that you are using? I don't think that there are Javascript bindings for selenium.

Comment: the error means there is no tag/s to be extracted. you may write the `page_source` and check it manually if the tag is in there.

Comment: I have edited for the code sample. I also tried with find element by name and xpath. Both worked with Firefox but not PhantomJS. (On python)

Comment: I tried to print the page_source just after reaching the page. Indeed, Firefox shows the right source code, where PhantomJS only has : `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: I edited with the full script. It is indeed a https website.
Thanks for your comments !

Answer (score 5):

I have solved my problem thanks to Artjom B. answer :

Just change in the code :

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
```

It was due to the ssl certificate I guess.

Comment: You can provide a link for reference where you got that answer from.

Comment: Somewhat tangential: if you're running a headless PhantomJS webdriver, throw this command when starting the server: ie. ```phantomjs --webdriver=8643 --ignore-ssl-errors=true```

For me, this solved Mink ElementNotFoundException errors I was getting when running Behat tests against an https base url with self-signed certificate.